# How do I get an Array from a different class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

How do I access my `Arraylist` from another class? I am trying to add two variables to a single position.

```
  var nc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteContent) as String
  var nt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteTitle) as String
           
  if (!nc.isEmpty() || !nt.isEmpty()) {

      get(noteArray(.add(nc,nt)
```

I am new to Kotlin and I don't know Java. I *think* I need to use a getter but I am not sure how do it.

My `arraylist`, "noteArray", always come up as unresolved reference; it's in my main class with the code.

```
lateinit var noteArray: MutableList<Note>
```

I am not sure if I need to provide a setter or something within the `mainActivity` but I think I can do it all from `activity2`.

Comment: To get a property from another class, usually you would need a reference to that class to call the property on, for example `otherClassInstance.noteArray.add(nc)`. However, Activities cannot be used in this way because unfortunately Android tears down and recreates Activity instances for a number of different reasons. You will have to use the “activity results API” (search the official documentation for that phrase). By the way, the above `as String` code will crash because a TextView is not a String. I think you want `.text.toString()` instead.

Comment: thank you i am looking it up it's confusing as there's so much there in activity results to read about.  Ihave ammended the text.tostring

Comment: It's not easy to communicate between Activities. Google recommends you only have a single Activity in your app and use Fragments for the different screens. Fragments can communicate by sharing the same ViewModel.

Comment: im looking up fragments now. The book i was following to learn Kotlin which i already realized wasn't great at explain things appears to have gaps. I think i can do what i want with these fragments and learn about activity result API when i am more advanced.

Comment: The trouble with Android is that best practices change pretty rapidly, so tutorials more than a year old are almost always obsolete. Best place to learn how to do anything specific is probably the official documentation, but even that is sometimes a bit behind.